# "Comics" or "Graphic novels"

Tags: word-choice

I have been watching TV series (Forever), And there was the following dialog:

> - Lucas: Isn't ordinary death exciting enough for you?
> - Henry:  Perhaps you've become desensitized with all your little **comics**.
> - Lucas: **Graphic novels**, Doc.

later in the same episode, the two terms were used by different people a lot of times to described the following:

[image]

My question: **Should I call them comics or Graphic books?**

Note: I checked some dictionaries, it seems the difference is the size of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within this context

`a comic or comic book`

would usually be magazine-style
and be stapled or similar.

Whereas

`a graphic novel`

would look like a book and be bound like a book.

The differences between a comic, a comic book and a graphic novel are essentially going to be the binding which will be determined by the number of pages and the episodic nature of the first two.

The difference between a graphic novel and a comic book is that the former is not periodical whereas the latter is.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graphic%20novel

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comic%20book

Comment: I would add that the original dialogue is a bit of humor, playing on the idea that "comics" are popularly regarded as a juvenile pastime, so adult fans prefer the term "graphic novels" which connotes intellectual rigor or artistic merit.